# iOS UIWebView not rendering foreign languages correctly

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in which I display a HTML file with foreign language content (in this case French), which was translated by Google.

The original English text is:

> Clear - used to stop all timers and clear the amounts shown to the far
>   right of the view.

The translation from Google is this:

> Effacer - permet d'arrêter toutes les minuteries et effacer les
>   montants indiqués à l'extrême droite de la vue.

This is what's displayed in the iPhone Simulator when French is the localized language:
[image: rendering of French translation in UIWebView]

This is the code I am using to load it:

```
//  determine what the language for this locale is...
NSString *sysLangCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

//  contatenate the language code to the filename
NSURL *indexURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instRST-%@", sysLangCode]
                withExtension:@"html"];

//  load it...
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexURL]];
```

I have looked in Google, SO and UIWebView to find any settings that would make this render correctly.  The font being used is Verdana.

What do I have to do to get this to render correctly?

Comment: How are you loading the HTML? it might have to do with some encoding problem

Comment: See edited question above where I show the code to load the HTML file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer:  see http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-fr.htm

This is the meta tag you have to use for French and other one-character languages:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

This works for all languages, including two-character languages, like Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: For anyone finding this: this is also true for react-native Webviews when using require().

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your html into a string (you must know the encoding of your file)

```
NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instRST-%@", sysLangCode] ofType:@"html"];
// use correct encoding
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:indexPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: If I use a stand-alone browser (Firefox, Safari or Chrome) NONE of them render it correctly either.  Does that help?